# No matching signal for QAction, no "go to slot" menu entry

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

[image: I have auto-generated QMainWindow (MainWindows) with QMenuBar (menuBar) and QMenu (menuWork) in it.]

I have problem with actually running QActions created with QtCreator. To run e.g. actionSystemSettings, I've added slot to MainWindows so it looks like this:

```
namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private slots:
    void on_menuWork_actionSystemSettings();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};
```

And this:

```
void MainWindow::on_menuWork_actionSystemSettings() {
    qDebug() << "Yay!";
}
```

It prompts:

> QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName: No matching signal for
>   on_menuWork_actionSystemSettings()

I guess it's some dumb mistake and I just forgot about something but reading documentation gives me nothing. I have no "go to slot" menu entry which should auto-create some template... at least Visual Studio for C# did that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation for `QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName()`:

> Searches recursively for all child objects of the given object, and
>   connects matching signals from them to slots of object that follow the
>   following form:
>
> void on_object-name_signal-name(signal-parameters);

So, I think your slot should have the following signature:

```
void MainWindow::on_actionSystemSettings_triggered()
{
    //
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you're defining slots the correct way is:

```
on_<widget_name>_<signal>
```

for instance if you have to name your slot

```
private slots:
    on_actionSystemSettings_triggered();
```

See [QtAutoConnect](http://programmingexamples.net/wiki/Qt/AutoConnect)